# 2D Vector initialization fails for values greater than 41260 in C++

Tags: c++, memory, multidimensional-array

I noticed that when I increase the dimension of a square 2D vector array, I start to get

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I was curious as to why that might happen and whether the first number of rows and columns which fails may give me more information (one would be expecting a power or two or something...).

Well, I started guessing and came to the conclusion that the error starts to appear for the `N > 42160`, meaning that `N = 42160` is still OK but `N = 42161` suddenly gives `SIGKILL`.

The whole code giving the error:

```
size_t N = 41261;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(N, std::vector<int>(N));
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrixCopy(N, std::vector<int>(N));
```

Do you know that number? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `41261 x 41261` `int`s requires ~6.5GB of ram.  Do you have a single contiguous chuck of ram big enough to handle that?

Comment: I don't know but vectors also have a memory limit. It's different on different architectures. C++ may have vectors but don't use it like there is infinite memory

Comment: @NathanOliver Wouldn't that cause a `std::bad_alloc` instead of a SIGKILL though? (still sounds like the most likely explanation regardless).

Comment: @NathanOliver Take that times 2 for the second matrix and you request roughly 13GB of memory.

Comment: Oh, the RAM might the problem. I didn't realise that because when I was working with a single array I could go into milions in size and it was all fine but in case of a 2D array, the N gets squared and then multiplied for the second matrix by 2. You're right. Thanks.

Comment: @ShreyanAvigyan the limit set by `std::vector` itself is typically far beyond the limit set by available memory (eg [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vdEWeqh11))

Comment: @Frank It very well could be throwing that and not being caught, which I think can lead to a SIGKILL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are allocating very big vector(at least 42161 * 42161 * 4 byte=7.1 GB) in stack which is cause you receive sigkill(i think more like std::bad_alloc) because you don't have enough memory i think it will also fail if you allocate on top of the heap. you should allocate memory exactly the size what you need. we have concept in OS that if programme going to allocate very large memory it will may cause some important part of system goes down and cause system break that's why OS will kill this programme.

read [OOM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html).

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 137 is out of memory, meaning your program took too much memory that the operating system had to kill it.
You could decrease the size, remove/replace entries you don't need or alloc and dealloc yourself in order to not have your program take too much space.